# create a component for Axios that can be used in different places with different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How can I create a component for Axios that I can use in different places with different values ​​??
I got stuck, what should I do?
This is what I have achieved so far

thank you for Helping

```
import axios from "axios";


const Axios = (props) => {
    const [posttitle, postbody] = useState([]);
    const [postuserid, postid] = useState([]);
    const fetchData = () => {
        const { postbodyapi } = props.postbodyapi;
        const postuseridapi = "https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players/james/lebron";
        const getbody = axios.get(postbodyapi);
        const getuseid = axios.get(postuseridapi);
        axios.all([getbody, getuseid]).then(axios.spread((...allData) => {
            const databody = allData[0].data.first_name;
            const datauseid = allData[1].config.url;
            postbody(databody);
            postid(datauseid);
        }))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {posttitle}


            <img src={postuserid} alt="asd"/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Axios;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom hook.

Create a hook called for example useAxios and hold only the fetching method inside of it, and the return state from that hook should be just data.
you can make it so it takes params like "URL, data, method", or make a few smaller hooks like useAxiosGet, useAxiosPost.

If you make a few smaller it will be easier to read and change something if needed.

Here is how I did it, an example of one specific Axios custom hook, use this for example to see how to build it.

```
useGetCar.js // custom axsios hook

import axios from 'axios';

const useGetCar = async (url, id) => {
    const result = await axios.post(url, {id: id});
    return result.data[0];
}

export default useGetCar


car.js // page component that displays data

import useGetCar from "@hooks/useGetCar";
let car_id = 1; // some that i send to api

// this function here is not exact from my code, 
//but I just wanted to provide you an example.

// I didn't include my original code because it is 
//from next.js app and I don't want to confuse u with that

async function getData() {
  let car = await useGetCar(`http://localhost/get_car.php`, car_id);
  return car;
}
```

Hope you understood what I'm saying, and I did not confuse you.
Feel free to ask anything if you don't understand something clearly.
Happy coding.

Comment: thanks for helping me but i have a question ... where is the "query" come from?

Comment: Sorry for that, that is from next.js I should have cleaned that, it is just a data, like 1, 2,3, etc. The second parameter is just an ID of a specific car I want to find inside of API.
I will change it so it is cleared.

Comment: Just edited the answer, take a look it should be okay now.

Comment: Gives an error says: Identifier 'car_id' is not in camel case

Comment: This is not the exact solving code for you. I can't write the exact solution for you because I would need to see more of your code, and structure. This is just an example of how to integrate the Axios logic in a custom hook and have reusable logic so you can repeat it on multiple pages, without copying the Axios logic in every component.

Comment: No problem, good luck, and happy coding.